# Emergency - I just reset --hard to my initial commit, is there a way to get my previous commits back, or is the whole project lost?

Tags: git

I haven't pushed to a remote repo yet. I am just so used to being able to pull from one that I didn't even think that there may not be a way to go back.

Comment: Check `git reflog` and then run another `git reset --hard` to the revision before you reverted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+reset+%22--hard%22

Comment: Commits — yes, non-pushed stuff — no.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Use "git reflog" and you will get a log of all your previous heads. You can check one out from there. Time to push this to a remote!